# WGET image files from source server using CRON to run a SCRIPT using a PHP-mySQL-based generated list

Tags: command-line, mysql, cron, wget

I am trying to setup a process which would do the following :

0. I have a folder where image files are stored (various resolutions : l/m/s/xs): WORKING !
1. each day, a mySQL table is updated/completed with image filenames : WORKING !
2. upon table "content refresh", I need to sort out which images are new : HALF-WAY THERE
3. upon new image files listing, I need to run a script (WGET) to download the source files
   from server A to specific folderS in server B : NOT THERE AT ALL

So far, I made it "by hand" :

- generated a TXT-file with each image filename **per line** (prefixed with the source path) :
  ...
  http://source-server/images/XS/image-filename_X.jpg
  http://source-server/images/XS/image-filename_Y.jpg
  http://source-server/images/XS/image-filename_Z.jpg
  ...
- ran the following :

*wget -i 20210331_1045_items_**M**.txt -P /var/www/target-server/htdocs/include/media/photos/items/**m** --limit-rate=256k*

The above approach works ! But I have to do it by myself.

Any ideas ?

Thank you all in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably use some SELECT statement in MySQL to determine which images are new. So use the INTO OUTFILE clause in that statement to export the list to a text file. Name it for example `/tmp/output1.txt`.

Setup a cron job that runs every 10 minutes or so and checks if the file `/tmp/output1.txt` is there. Once the file is there, rename it to for example `/tmp/output2.txt` (to avoid triggering the job again) and run wget on that file.

That's of course only a basic idea that needs some improvements - for example, you may need to check the size of file `/tmp/output1.txt` to avoid picking it up by the script while it is still being exported from MySQL. You can do it for example by checking the file size and storing it in another temporary file. When the file `/tmp/output1.txt` is there, compare it's size with size stored in the temporary file. If it is different (or if the temporary file does not exist at all), store the size in temporary file and exit - the cron job will be called again after 10 minutes. If the size is equal, remove the temporary file and proceed with wget.

Comment: Thanks, Raj ! I didn't know about that INTO OUTFILE thing.

Comment: I just proceeded with the creation of a PHP/mySQL script that checks for the newly added image files, and dynamically creates a TXT-list using PHP "file_exists" and "file_put_contents" functions, while adding the source URL as prefix for each file.

Comment: Now, back to the CRON thing where I would pick-up the TXT-list to look ONLY for the "new or missing" image files. I still have some fine-tuning to do, like empty or delete the list file, ...

Comment: All in all, I will probably end up with 2 crons : the #1 to check the new image filenames from the DB and create a new/missing files list; the #2 to effectively look into that list and WGET the listed files.

Comment: if(file_exists($filenameL)){//do nothing} else {
      $missing_image .= $source_path.'L/'.$img_filename.PHP_EOL;
      file_put_contents($missing_list, $missing_image);
     }